# Panda python Eval error when no results come up

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

looking for some help with my code. Im running selenium loop keyword searches and using panda to get the table search results, but when an search term doesnt come back with any results I would get an error, if it does have result but no match with oval filter it keep running.

Example once the search reaches "Cedarcrest" it would output pandas.errors.UndefinedVariableError: name 'Description' is not defined.

This is my code, how can I fix so it would skip the search terms that yield no results?

```
import time
import requests
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


class KW_POST_BOT(object):
    def __init__(self, browser, search_engine_url, kw_list, package):
        self.browser = browser
        self.package = package
        self.search_engine_url = search_engine_url
        self.kw_list = kw_list

    def main(self):
        self.browser.get("https://www.dnv.org/building-development/look-building-and-trades-permits")
        ###   MAIN LOOP
        #   INJECT KEY WORD LIST

        #   LOOPS THROUGH KW_LIST AS KW
        for kw in self.kw_list:
            print("*" * 30)
            print("Searching " + kw)
            print("*" * 30)
            print("Finding Data Table")
            print("-" * 30)
            #   WAIT 3 SECONDS
            time.sleep(3)
            #   LOCATE ELEMENT AND CLEAR
            elem = self.browser.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                             "/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/app-root/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/ng2-completer/div/input").clear()
            #   LOCATE ELEMENT AND SEND KEYS :  KW VARIABLE
            elem = self.browser.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                             "/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/app-root/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/ng2-completer/div/input").send_keys(
                kw)
            #   PRESS ENTER
            elem = self.browser.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                             "/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/app-root/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/ng2-completer/div/input").send_keys(
                Keys.ENTER)
            #   WAIT 3 SECONDS
            time.sleep(3)

            #   PRINT IN TERMINAL
            table_trs = self.browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//table[@id="case_table"]/tbody/tr')
            value_list = []
            for row in table_trs[1:]:
                value_list.append({
                    # 'Permit': row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[0].text,
                    'Address': row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[1].text,
                    # 'Value': row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[2].text,
                    # 'Contact': row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[3].text,
                    'Status': row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[4].text,
                    'Date': row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[5].text,
                    'Description': row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[6].text
                })

            df = pd.DataFrame(value_list)
            filtered_list = df[
                df.eval("Description.str.contains('New') & Date.str.contains('2018|2019|2020|2021|2022').values")]

            #   TURN THEWEB OBJECT INTO TEXT AND ENCODE IN UTF-8
            # table_data = table_data.text.encode("utf-8")
            print(filtered_list)


#   DEFINE KEW_WORDS LIST TO INPUT
key_words = ["Eldon", "Ruby", "Bracknell", "Pelly", "Sunset", "Edgewood", "Sycamore", "Lodge",
             "Virginia", "Loraine", "Kendal", "Emerald", "Dudley", "Highland", "Highland", "Montroyal", "Ranger",
             "Shirley", "Cedarcrest", "Lions", "Sunnycrest", "Beaumont", "Tudor", "Winona", "Canterbury",
             "Beaconsfield", "Hampshire", "Devon", "Essex", "Derby", "Belgrave", "Cheviot", "Parliament", "Ruskin",
             "Handsworth", "Rialto", "Belvedere", "Marineview", "Mapleridge", "Pheasant", "Ruthina", "Marigold",
             "Marigold", "Glenwood", "Timberline", "Ventura", "Monteray", "Greenway", "Valencia", "Hermosa", "Vienna",
             "Genoa", "Saville", "Granada", "Lucerne", "Verona", "Croydon", "Silverdale", "Lewister", "Langdale",
             "Quinton", "Carolyn", "Wavertree", "Wentworth", "Leovista", "Trenton", "Evergreen", "Chelsea", "Crystal",
             "Sylvan", "Alpine", "Bonita", "Palisade", "Blueridge", "Skyline", "Glencanyon", "Delmar", "Dolores",
             "Delbrook", "Linnae", "Teviot", "Belvista", "Prospect", "Primrose", "Edgewood", "Patterdale", "Newdale",
             "Crestwood", "Montroyal", "Glenview", "Arundel", "Ranger", "Capilano", "Salvador", "Grace", "East", "June",
             "Cliffridge", "Glenn"]

#   INSTANTIATE KW_POST_BOT AS bot
bot = KW_POST_BOT(webdriver.Firefox(), "https://www.dnv.org/building-development/look-building-and-trades-permits",
                  key_words, [])

bot.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a try/except block like this, that would first run the code and if pandas raise an error it would just print a message and go on the next search term, avoiding stopping the program

```
try:
    //your pandas code here
except pd.errors.UndefinedVariableError:
    print("No results")
```

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html?highlight=try%20except

Comment: thanks, I have added it in try and except. Another issue, im trying to export the results to CVS file,  the using code  filtered_list.to_csv('raw_data.csv', index=False) but the cvs file would only save the last search term results, all the previous found results will not be in the cvs.

Comment: Because everytime you are creating a new dataframe with `df = pd.DataFrame(value_list)`   To get over that either every time export the dataframe as csv (so you will have one csv per keyword) or create a global DataFrame before searching for each keyword, and concat  the output (filtered_list) to this global DataFrame. and at the end of your program export it to csv. Hence you will have one csv with all results.

Comment: See : https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html  You can also write a csv and reopen it but it will cause more Read/Write operation